# Concurrency procedure calls from different back-ends

Tags: sql, sql-server, rabbitmq, queue

I have a procedure that increments a counter in a table. This procedure increments a value when it is called from a back-end. The problem is when this procedure is called in parallel by several Java consumers, as shown below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/liOfL.png

And the content of the procedure simply adds one number to a column to check if all known messages in a queue are complete.

`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[INCREMENT_TABLE_COUNT]
(
  @id_entry INT
)

AS BEGIN

 DECLARE @TOTAL INT = 0
 DECLARE @CREATED INT = 0

  -- I've tried using this set in isolation, but sometimes the select below gets the same number and doesn't increment correctly
  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED 
  
  BEGIN TRAN
  BEGIN
          SELECT
          @TOTAL = Total_Accounts
          ,@CREATED = Created_Accounts
          FROM table_count col
          WHERE col.first_col =  @id_entry

          IF @CREATED < @TOTAL
          BEGIN
          BEGIN TRANSACTION;

            SET @CREATED = @CREATED + 1 -- increment a value based on the select above, 
                                                -- I suspects that sometimes it gets the same select value twice

            UPDATE table_count SET
              Created_Accounts = @CREATED 
            WHERE col.first_col = @id_entry 
         COMMIT TRANSACTION;
         END

  END
  COMMIT

  SELECT
  , @TOTAL as Total_Accounts
  , @CREATED as Created_Accounts

  RETURN
END
```

`

I expect that when this procedure is called by several back-ends, It holds the lock on the table and guarantee the transaction creating an output like this:

| Total_Accounts | Created_Accounts |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 |
| ... | ... |
| 2000 | 1997 |
| 2000 | 1998 |
| 2000 | 1999 |
| 2000 | 2000 |

But when I get the application Log, calling the procedure, I get this output below, the created account duplicates, indicating that the select inside the procedure is getting the same value twice and increment the value.

| Total_Accounts | Created_Accounts |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 |
| ... | ... |
| 2000 | 1997 |
| **2000** | **1998** |
| **2000** | **1998** |
| 2000 | 1999 |

I checked that I had 2000 messages, and the procedure was called exactly 2000 times but the total of created account **sometimes** doesn't achieve 2000.

To overcome this, I've tried Setting the `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` inside the procedure. But the `READ COMMITTED` didn't work. I also try setting the `BEGIN` and the `COMMIT` in different parts of the procedure to try to commit the update, before the next select made by the Procedure.

What's the best way to avoid this update problem ?

Comment: You aren't however holding a lock, you need to specify, eg `with (updlock, holdlock)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic race condition since the values can be changed by another session between the initial `SELECT` and subsequent `UPDATE`. Although this could be addressed with a more restrictive isolation level and/or hints, a single atomic auto-commit `UPDATE` statement will address the concurrency issue and, IMHO, easier to understand and maintain.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[INCREMENT_TABLE_COUNT]
  @id_entry INT
AS
UPDATE table_count 
SET Created_Accounts += 1 
OUTPUT inserted.Total_Accounts, inserted.Created_Accounts 
WHERE 
    first_col = @id_entry 
    AND Created_Accounts < Total_Accounts;
```

Comment: Thank you! This was an effective and elegant way to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

To solve this with lock hints add UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK on the SELECT:

```
SELECT 
    @TOTAL = Total_Accounts
   ,@CREATED = Created_Accounts
FROM table_count col with (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK)
WHERE col.first_col =  @id_entry
```